# Meaning of @# in shell

Tags: shell

I recently got this script to match a string in command line aguments:

```
if [[ "$@" == "${@#foo}" ]]; then echo "not found" ; else echo "found"; fi
```

Looks like it does negative search. What is the meaning of `@#` exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `man bash` under `Parameter Expansion`:

> ```
> ${parameter#word}
> ```
>
> ```
> ${parameter##word}
> ```
>
> Remove  matching  prefix  pattern.  The *word* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern
>   matches the beginning of the value of *parameter*, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of *parameter* with the shortest matching pattern (the  `#`  case)  or the  longest matching pattern (the `##` case) deleted.  If *parameter* is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to
>   each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern
>   removal  operation  is
>                 applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

The `$@` is expanded to the list of script arguments each enclosed into quotes:

```
"$1" "$2" "$3"...
```

thus the `"${@#foo}"` would expand to a list of quoted script arguments with stripped out prefix `foo` if such prefix exist in any of expanded strings, i.e. the script `test`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${@#foo}"
```

invoked as:

```
./test abc foodef
```

outputs

```
abc def
```